# Why do negative scores of example questions on Area 51 get reset to 0 whenever someone votes to close them?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, area-51, example-questions

I just cast the final close vote to close some example questions on an Area 51 proposal. Those questions had very low scores, around -3 and -5.

However, as soon as the questions got closed, their vote scores were reset back to 0. Upvoting or downvoting them changes their scores to 1 and -1 respectively, so it's not simply the display on my end.

I haven't seen this happen with positively-scored example questions: when they get closed, their positive score is retained. It only seems to happen for negatively-scored example questions.

Why do the vote scores of example questions on Area 51 proposals with negative scores get reset to 0 when someone votes to close them?

**Update:** This seems to not only happen when an example question *reaches the threshold and gets closed*, but when *anyone* casts a vote to close the question. As an example, [this question](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124848/agriculture/124963#124963) had -2 score and three close votes. Right after someone else cast a close vote, its score was reset to 0. I then downvoted it and took the below screenshot:

> [image]

Then, I cast the final vote to close it, and *immediately* afterwards, the question's score was reset to 0 again:

> [image]

To test if it really was caused by the close vote/close action and not simply because someone upvoted it in the meantime, I voted to close [another example question](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124848/agriculture/124931#124931) with -4 score and no close votes.

> [image]

But *immediately* after I voted to close it, its score was 0 again (once I refreshed the page):

> [image]

I *highly doubt* that four upvotes would come in the span of split-seconds.

Is this behavior intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: No-repro. I have VTC (across all of first, middle, last) several questions with negative scores on more than one proposal in the last two months, all of the closed which still have their (sometimes quite large) negative score.

Comment: @Nij I just voted to close [this example question](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124848/agriculture/125050#125050). It had a score of -3 when I cast the final vote, and as soon as I did, its score changed to 0. (I then downvoted it myself to -1.)

Comment: That question has a score of -4.

Comment: @Nij I suspect it's caching. I also cast the final vote to close [this one](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124848/agriculture/124962#124962), which had a score of -5 or so before that, but was reset to 0 when I voted. It now only scores -1 because someone else cast a downvote afterwards.

Comment: @Nij I've added a couple more repro cases to the question.

Comment: I have no idea, but I'll add I've seen this all the time. I usually just manually load the score breakdown for the example to recalculate the score for it, because it's not clearing the votes just changing the denormalized score to 0 on the example.

Comment: @animuson I know what denormalized score is, and how it's recalculated when someone loads the vote breakdown. However, it's unexpected that it would be reset to 0 whenever someone votes to close. Why does this happen? Is it intentional?

Comment: Like I said, I've no idea. It's only ever been an annoyance to me. Robert might have known if it was truly a feature but I cannot phathom what the reason would have been myself and I kind of doubt anyone else here has the slightest clue.